# C programming error - counter already defined?

Tags: c

***ERRORS:***

1) _counter already defined error

2) one or more multiply defined symbols found

structure.h:

```
extern int counter = 0;
```

List.c:

in one method i increment the counter.

```
++counter;
```

in another method i set the counter to a value within an object
llist->taskID = counter;

Messages.c:

use counter for while loop

```
while(counter < 1)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

why does this error occur? I did a ctrl F and searched for all the instances i use counter... these are the only instances i use it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your header file `structure.h` should only have a declaration (not a definition), like:

```
  extern int counter;
```

One (only) of the implementation files, conventionally the `*.c` file containing `main`, should have a definition like

```
  int counter = 0;
```

Comment: where could i give it a value then though? if i try to give it a value in main i get a bunch of other errors.....

Comment: The definition should of course happen outside of any function, preferably before any function in the file containing `main`. I strongly suggest **reading a good C programming book** (on paper, in a university library). Learning a language only by trial and error is a huge waste of time; reading a book will make you learn faster!